# Does convexity imply this inequality?

Tags: functions, inequality

Consider the following inequality,

$$(\alpha(x+y)+(1-\alpha)(x’+y’))f\left(\frac{\alpha x+(1-\alpha)x’}{\alpha(x+y)+(1-\alpha)(x’+y’)}\right)\le \alpha(x+y)f\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\right)+(1-\alpha) (x’+y’)f\left(\frac{x’}{x’+y’}\right)$$

where $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $0\le x,x’,y,y’,\alpha\le 1$.

**Question:** Is convexity of $f$ sufficient for the inequality to hold?

---

**Attempt:**

- Define
  $$h(x,x’,y,y’,\alpha)= \frac{\alpha x+(1-\alpha)x’}{\alpha(x+y)+(1-\alpha)(x’+y’)}$$
  $$g(x,y)= \frac{x}{x+y}$$ For any value of $\alpha,x,x',y,y'$, the value $h(x,x’,y,y’,\alpha)$ always lies between $g(x,y)$ and $g(x’,y’)$ (see my other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579075/relating-fraction-to-convex-combinations-of-numerators-and-denominators-of-two-o)).
- Using the above fact, the inequality states that the function evaluated at some intermediate point times some scalar ($A+B$) is less than or equal to $A$ times the function evaluated at one extreme plus $B$ times the function evaluated at the other extreme. Intuitively, this seems related to convexity but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Jensen Inequality:

For any convex $f$, and nonnegative reals $r_1,r_2$,  $$r_1 f(x_1)+r_2 f(x_2)\ge (r_1+r_2)f\left(\dfrac{r_1x_1+r_2x_2}{r _1+r_2}\right)$$

and convexity of $f$ is sufficient with applying $\;r_1=\alpha(x+y)\;$, $\;r_2=(1-\alpha)(x’+y’)\;$, $\;x_1=\dfrac{x}{x+y}\;$ and $\;x_2=\dfrac{x’}{x’+y’}\;$ for the Jensen Inequality.

Also the Jensen Inequality can be generalized for n values.